# Запрет кеширования

Tags: php, javascript

У меня такой вопрос. Как отключить кеширование в браузере? Нужно чтобы часы показывали настоящее время. Пробовал такой заголовок, но он не сработал.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0");
echo "<h1>".date("H:i:s")."</h1>";
?>
```

Редактирование `*.htaccess` файла тоже не помогло.

Comment: А какое время показывают часы?

Comment: Текущее закешированное время на сервере. А мне надо просто текущее :-)

Comment: А как вы узнаете, что это закешированное время на сервере?

Comment: Нет, с сервера приходит нормальное время. Кеширует страницу браузер и показывает не идущие часы, а остановившееся. Вот.

Comment: Этого ответа я и ждал! С чего вы взяли, что они будут идти? PHP не дает динамики. Хотя, можете добавить meta тег с обновлением странички и часы пойдут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не закешированное значение, а просто значение, которое сервер отдает браузеру.
Используйте следующую конструкцию, чтобы сделать коряво то, что вы пытаетесь:

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>
```

Comment: А можно как-нибудь без перезагрузки стр?

Comment: Например JavaScript.

Comment: Можно, учите JavaScript. Он вам позволит сделать часы и не только. Извращаться на тему можно сколько угодно, вплоть до загрузки даты посредством Ajax с сервера.

Comment: А можно пример какого-нибудь простого JavaScript кода?

Comment: http://krigler.narod.ru/script/clock3.htm здесь смотрите, в поиске много примеров

Answer (score 2):

> Как отключить кеширование в браузере?

Вопрос подразумевает ответ. Его отключают в браузере. :)

```
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: Я имел в виду как попросить браузера чтобы он не кешировал страницу.
P.S. Впервые слышу чтобы кеширование отключали в самом браузере...

Comment: Тогда так.
<pre>
<code>
php
  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
  header('Pragma: no-cache');

</code>
</pre>

>P.S. Впервые слышу чтобы кеширование отключали в самом браузере...

вообще-то его там можно отключить ;) на стороне клиента

Comment: Ха-ха. Эти 4 строчки случайно не с Wikipedia? Надеюсь, все знают что они не работают. 

Shrek, у вас этот код сработал? У вас часы пошли или как у меня показали время в кеше?

Comment: У меня показывает реальное время.<br />
у меня много всякой хрени отдельным файлом чтобы не искать в инете есть, так что оттуда взял.